# Count number of lines under each header in a text file using bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I can do this easily in python or some other high level language. What I am interested in is doing this with bash.

Here is the file format:

```
head-xyz
item1
item2
item3
head-abc
item8
item5
item6
item9
```

What I would like to do is print the following output:

```
head-xyz: 3
head-abc: 4
```

header will have a specific pattern similar to the example i gave above. items also have specific patterns like in the example above. I am only interested in the count of items under each header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '/head/{h=$0}{c[h]++}END{for(i in c)print i, c[i]-1}' input.file
```

Breakdown:

- `/head/{h=$0}`

  For every line matching `/head/`, set variable `h` to record the header.
- `{c[h]++}`

  For every line in the file, update the array `c`, which stores a map from header string to line count.
- `END{for(i in c)print i, c[i]-1}`

  At the end, loop through the keys in array `c` and print the key (header) followed by the value (count).  Subtract one to avoid counting the header itself.

Comment: I won't count using `awk` as "doing this with bash." You can as well invoke the Python interpreter.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Yes, many questions which are related to *doing things in a Linux shell environment* are tagged with `bash` while `shell` or `command-line` would be a better choice. But how should the OP tag this with `awk` if he does not know that `awk` is a nice tool for that job? Note that posting an answer which suggests an alternative like `you can use ...` is pretty usual on SO. If you want to use Python, use Python. I would use awk.

Comment: The point is, this can be done very easily with pure bash. No need to invoke anything.

Comment: Post an answer, that's what the site is about! :)

Comment: I didn't post the answer because this kind of question is generally annoying: "I know this is easy in language X but now I want to do it in language Y. Give me the code." Easy things in language X are often easy in language Y, too. It's the "show us your effort" thing, you know.

Comment: I admit that there are some cases where your comment applies, but I still think this one is ok. Common! post a bash answer!! :)

Comment: quirky problem but I did a try

Comment: @4ae1e1 FYI, I actually did complete my task by modifying a Python script I was using, much before I posted here. The motivation behind my question was to LEARN about how to do it in bash or using shell utilities because I am not so good with them. I am sorry it was annoying to you but I dont think I forced you to participate.

Comment: @powerrox Best way to learn: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html . No snark. I read it once and now I can at least answer 95% of your Bash questions.

Comment: @4ae1e1 thank you for the pointer. Everyone has their own preferred way of learning. I learn best by example. Thank you for your inputs and I am glad you can answer 95% of my bash questions (although, in all fairness, you didnt answer this one).

Comment: @hek2mgl: I updated your answer to include a breakdown of how it works.  Do you mind double-checking it?  This is a really instructive use of `awk`.

Answer (score 3):

Note: Bash version 4 only (uses associative arrays)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FILENAME="$1"
declare -A CNT

while read -r LINE || [[ -n $LINE ]]
do
    if [[ $LINE =~ ^head ]]; then HEADLINE="$LINE"; fi
    if [ ${CNT[$HEADLINE]+_} ];
    then
        CNT[$HEADLINE]=$(( ${CNT[$HEADLINE]} + 1 ))
    else
        CNT[$HEADLINE]=0
    fi
done < "$FILENAME"

for i in "${!CNT[@]}"; do echo "$i: ${CNT[$i]}"; done
```

Output:

```
$ bash countitems.sh input
head-abc: 4
head-xyz: 3
```

Does this answer your question @powerrox ?

Comment: This works nicely, tested in a VM. However, my environment is constrained to bash 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't consider `sed` a high-level language, here's another approach:

```
for file in head-*; do
    echo "$file: \c"
    sed -n '/^head-/,${
        /^head-/d
        /^item[0-9]/!q
        p
    }
    ' <$file | wc -l
done
```

In English, the sed script does

- Don't print by default
- Within lines matching `/^head-/` to end of file

  - Delete the "head line"
  - After that, quit if you find a non-item line
  - Otherwise, print the line

And `wc -l` to count lines.